# Spatial query on DB2 is spiking up cpu

Tags: db2, spatial, db2-luw

1. DB version is 10.5
2. This is the first time we are doing spatial queries and we have this spatial query that returns about 2500 rows in only a couple seconds but behind the screen its spiking up our database server's CPU.
3. Reaching out to this group to see if they can provide any pointers around any  specific database configurations we need to revisit or if can point out any tweaks to the query?
4. DB2 spatial functions that we are using in our query look like as below:

   - `db2gse.St_buffer(db2gse.St_point(-87.87, 42.36,1), 75, STATUTE MILE')`

Comment: Why is spiking CPU bad? Would you rather it sit idle?

Comment: its spiking upto 90-100% :(

Comment: Would the query concerned  run often enough to cause high CPU-utilization alerts and/or increase billing-prices (if you are paying for CPU time)? Consider editing the  question to include relevant configuration details (cpu/memory /i-o bandwidth resources allocated for Db2, table details (partitioned? distributed?) tablespace details for your spatial data,  whether you tried the spatial index advisor (gseidx) if relevant, and whether you studied the access plan (db2exfmt) for the query. You may want to use db2batch to quantify the impact of any changes you make.

Comment: Yes, the concerned query would run often enough. Will need to look into gseidx and db2exfmt      Thanks for the feedback.